# Raspberry Pi Pico - USB host with USB hub has anyone got it to work

Tags: usb, pi-pico

Has anybody got a USB hub working with the Raspberry Pi Pico.

I've got a person project that i want to use a mouse and a keyboard but when i add a hub it all falls apart.

So I wen't and tried the Raspberry Pi example on there git repo and it seems to cause the same issue that my project does

https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples/tree/master/usb/host

```
A device with address 5 is mounted

 **PANIC**

ep 0 out was already available
```

All I have is connected is a hub and a keyboard. The only thing I can think of as being a problem is that I have a USB 3 hub.